# Specifying the frequencies for msts objects

Tags: time, series

I have hourly level data for one month which has both daily as well as weekly seasonality. I am defining it in the following way
msts_cons<-xts_series %>% msts(seasonal.periods = c(24, 7*24),ts.frequency=365.25*24)
 Is this specification correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? By which means correct?

Comment: I'm getting confused about frequencies. So the frequency should be 365*24(for 24 hours in a day) and the seasonal periods are at a daily level(that's why I've taken 24) and also at a weekly level (that's why I've taken 24*7). I just wanted to verify if this specification is correct in my context